# I can't get this piece of code to work -> $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] <-

Tags: php

I'm trying to run a very simple script to test the "action=echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];" in a HTML form (with php start and end on it but this site doesn't allow me to introduce those chars). This is the script:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { echo "it works"; } ?>

<form name="test" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
```

Problem is whenever I hit the submit button I get a "Safari can't find the file" error stating that "no file exists at the address" where I run the script.

What am I doing wrong here?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Eduardo

Comment: I tried to fix your script. I hope it worked. Note there are buttons in the Stack Overflow editor with which you can give blocks of code the right markup. Basically, indenting it 4 spaces is enough, and you won't have to mangle your HTML and PHP to be able to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. I think you are using `mod_rewrite` and that's why it cannot find the file.

Comment: <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   echo "it works";
  }
?>

<form name="sendemail" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>

it didn't work...I still get an error "no file exists at /script location/<.

Comment: Safari tries to open this file when I hit the submit button:

file:///Users/eduardonpinto/Sites/example1/%3C?php%20echo%20$_SERVER%5B'REQUEST_URI'%5D;%20?%3E

Comment: This is not related to the browser. Please make sure that your file has the .php extension and also if your server has php installed.. it seems that the php code is not recognized

Comment: Thank you Matei, it seems that everything works fine when I open the files from localhost...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set the action attribute of the form, if you want to post data to the same page.

```
<form name="test" method="post"> 
  ...
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

should do it.

Cheers!

Comment: <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   echo "it works";
  }
?>

<form name="sendemail" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>

Without the action attribute when I click Submit it just reloads the HTML page. I never see the "it works" PHP result...

Comment: English please! Pasting the same code back again does not make a whole lotta sense.

Comment: Sorry. I removed the action attribute form the code and now when I press the submit button the page reloads and I don't receive the desired output ("it works").

Comment: @EduardoPinto add the html of your form so that we can understand what is going wrong there

Comment: I'm getting confused...I've already replied to your answer with the PHP and HTML form code (modified, without action attribute) but you told me to write in English. The code I'm using now is this:

<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { echo "it works"; } ?> 

<form name="sendemail" method="post"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br> 
</form>

Comment: @EduardoPinto adding code in the comments is not advisable as it is hardly readable, although you can edit your question to add the working code.  Anyway, I tried the code and it works as expected.  May be you are not using localhost to open the file. Be kind enough to share the url using which you access the file in the browser.

Comment: that's it! I've tried to open the HTML file using localhost and it works like a charm. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @EduardoPinto, if the answer was correct and helpful, please accept the answer so that other users with the same problem can identify the correct answer.